# Show that $Z(M_{s \wedge t} - M_{r \wedge t})$ is a martingale when $M$ is a martingale and $Z \in \mathscr{F}_r$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

> Show that for a martingale $M$ and every $0 \leq r < s$ and every bounded $\mathscr{F}_r$ measurable variable $Z$, $N_t = Z(M_{s \wedge t} - M_{r \wedge t})$ is a martingale.

I want to compute $E[N_t \mid \mathscr{F}_u]$, and for $u \geq r$ there is no problem, but I don't know what to say for $u < r$. It's clear that the value of the martingale should be zero for $u < r$, but since $Z$ is not necessarily $\mathscr{F}_u$ measurable I cannot remove it from the conditional expectation as I would like.

According to Jean-Francois Le Gall (this is part of a proof in his book, *Brownian Motion, Martingales, and Stochastic Calculus*), the proof of this fact is "easy".

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Good point. The author of the book is Jean-Francois Le Gall and he claims the proof of this fact is easy. I can't think he'd make an oversight that big so I changed the wording of the question to more closely match his. Maybe it makes a difference.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist If that's the case he made the same error twice, since later he defines an elementary process in $L^2(M)$ ($M$ is a martingale):

$$H_s(\omega) = \sum_{i = 0}^{p - 1} H_{(i)}(\omega) \mathbb{1}_{(t_i, t_{i + 1}]}(s)$$

with $H_{(i)} \in \mathscr{F}_{t_i}$ and then, when constructing the integral of $H$ w.r.t. $M$, claims that

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{p - 1} H_{(i)} (M_{t_{i+1}\wedge t} - M_{t_{i}\wedge t})$$

is a martingale for similar reasons.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist That said, he has an exercise asking to show that $Z M_t$ is a martingale when $Z \in \mathscr{F}_0$ and claims this was used in the context of the proof I mentioned above. Not sure what to make of that. Maybe he managed to confuse himself.

Comment: Le Gall is correct. The fact that $N_u = 0$ for $u \le r$ is enough to show that $N$ is a martingale. This also guarantees that $N$ is adapted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u < r$. We have

\begin{align*}
E[N_t \vert \mathscr{F}_u] & = E[Z(M_{s \wedge t} -M_{r \wedge t}) \vert \mathscr{F}_u] \\
&= E[ZE[M_{s \wedge t} -M_{r \wedge t} \vert \mathscr{F}_r] \vert \mathscr{F}_u] \\
&= 0.
\end{align*}

Note however that $N_u = 0$, so $E[N_t \vert \mathscr{F}_u] = N_u$, as desired.

Comment: Ah. It is easy. Thanks!